# How to add new entry to LDAP server with Golang?

Tags: go, ldap

I had an issue trying to add a new entry into my LDAP server. The error I get is the following: LDAP Result Code 65 "Object Class Violation": no structural object class provided. If anyone could give me some input on why, that would be helpful.

I'm binded to the server, so it seems like I just have an issue with the actual entry attributes.. but I'm not sure where to fix it.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
//  "github.com/go-ldap/ldap"
  "gopkg.in/ldap.v2"
  "log"
)

//List of constants
const (
  host = "127.0.0.1"
  port = "389"
  hostPort = host + ":" + port
  userID = "cn=admin,dc=test123,dc=com"
  password = "password"
)

//Main function to be called
func main() {
  addEntries()
}

//Add entries function
func addEntries(){
  fmt.Println("Adding started")

  //Initialize connection
  l, err := ldap.Dial("tcp", hostPort)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer l.Close()

  //Bind to the LDAP server
  bindusername := "cn=admin,dc=test123,dc=com"
  bindpassword := "password"

  err = l.Bind(bindusername, bindpassword)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return
  }

  fmt.Println("Testing.")

  //Create new Add request object to be added to LDAP server.
  a := ldap.NewAddRequest("ou=groups,dc=test123,dc=com")
  a.Attribute("cn", []string{"gotest"})
  a.Attribute("objectClass" ,[]string{"top"})
  a.Attribute("description", []string{"this is a test to add an entry using golang"})
  a.Attribute("sn" ,[]string{"Google"})

  fmt.Println("Testing.")
  add(a , l)




}
func add(addRequest *ldap.AddRequest , l *ldap.Conn) {
  err := l.Add(addRequest)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Entry NOT done",err)
  } else {
    fmt.Println("Entry DONE",err)
  }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you the issue. In your object-class list you only have "top". You need to add what the error says - a "structural class" to the (slice) list. Check with your LDAP directory's schema, but the quickest way is just search for existing entries at that base-dn & inspect what their objectclass list looks like.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't know those different attributes weren't optional. I simply just copied the objectclasses from my other entries in the LDAP server and it worked. But how do you know what attributes are necessary in an entry?

Comment: hard to explain in a comment, so put some pointers in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common errors when creating LDAP objects is a missing `objectClass` and/or an object's mandatory attributes (e.g. `uid`, `cn` etc.) Here are some techniques to identify these requirements.

---

You can query an LDAP server's schema like so:

```
ldapsearch -x -h my.example.com -b "cn=schema" -s base "(objectclass=*)"
```

The output is not very human-readable, but if you know the exact `objectClass` you are looking for, things can become a little clearer.

For example the `objectClass: person` definition may looks like this:

```
objectClasses: ( 2.5.6.6 NAME 'person' DESC 'Defines entries that generically
 represent people.' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ sn ) MAY ( description $ se
 eAlso $ telephoneNumber $ userPassword ) )
```

So you can see this is a `STRUCTURAL` objectClass (supplementing `top`) and if one were to create such a `person` LDAP object, it:

- must include: `cn` and `sn`
- and optionally: `description`, `seeAlso`, `telephoneNumber` or `userPassword`

---

Individual attribute types are defined like so:

```
attributeTypes: ( 2.5.4.3 NAME ( 'cn' 'commonName' ) DESC 'This is the X.500 c
 ommonName attribute, which contains a name of an object.  If the object corre
 sponds to a person, it is typically the persons full name.' SUP 2.5.4.41 EQUA
 LITY 2.5.13.2 ORDERING 2.5.13.3 SUBSTR 2.5.13.4 )
```

Comment: Quick question, when I use `ldapsearch -x -h my.example.com -b "cn=schema" -s base "(objectclass=*)"` it just shows me the numResponses:1 (which means it exists.) How do I actually view the schema?

Comment: if you could answer my previous comment that'd be much appreciated!